# Hover not working with jQuery Tools - jQuery

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, hover, jquery-animate, jquery-tools

When I add [jQuery Tools](http://flowplayer.org/tools/tooltip/index.html) to my page, hover effect on links doesn't work. Without it, it works.

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.color.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.5/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
$("a").hover(
function() {
    $(this).animate({color: "white"}, 400);
}, function() {
    $(this).animate({color: "black"}, 400);
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: do you get any errors? can you provide a link to your page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you switch the color plugin and the tools `<script>` tags the animation works

http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/gJjAZ/

Question will be: does that make the tooltip not work? :)