# Hover not working with jQuery Tools - jQuery

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, hover, jquery-animate, jquery-tools

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Hover not working with jQuery Tools - jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7164204/hover-not-working-with-jquery-tools-jquery)

When I add [jQuery Tools](http://flowplayer.org/tools/tooltip/index.html) to my page, hover effect on links doesn't work. Without it, it works.

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.5/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.color.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
    $(".header").live({ 
        mouseenter: function() {
            $(this).animate({color: "black"}, 400);
        }, 
        mouseleave: function() {
            $(this).animate({color: "white"}, 400);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Another question: does jQuery Tools tooltip work with jQuery live?

Err, I don't think you guys understood it.. it works when I don't add:

```
<script src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.5/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Which browser version and which version of jQuery?  I would not recommend jQuery Tools as any viable long-term solution. It has not been updated for about a year (since jQuery 1.4.2), has issues with newer browsers (IE9), requires a ton of manual markup, it's not well supported and the developer has clearly lost interest.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the syntax you are using for .live doesn't work in jQuery 1.4.2, it was added in jquery 1.4.3. try binding this way instead:

```
<script src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.5/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.color.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
    $(".header").live('mouseenter mouseleave',function(e){ 
        $(this).animate({color: e.type === "mouseenter" ? "black" : "white" }, 400);
    });
});
</script>
```

EDIT

Also, the jquery tools is overriding your original jquery script include, that is why i omitted it.